# How to change Google service account v- Cloud Storage when running from local eclipse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

When starting spring boot app that uses cloud storage, I see this

```
m c.g.c.s.c.DefaultCredentialsProvider.<init> - Default credentials provider for service account lo*ideal@api-project-8##9.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Where is this id coming from, and how can I change it?

In another computer it is admlocal****, how can I change it on this computer too?

Error:

```
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "l*eal@api-project-8##429.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "l*deal@api-project-8##29.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start by checking the `application.properties` file of your [Springboot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/spring-cloud-gcp-core.html#_credentials) app. Credentials can be set either by means of,

- Setting the credentials location, or

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:/usr/local/key.json
```

- By directly setting the property value of

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.encoded-key
```

If the credentials are not specified in the properties file, then you can check the credentials file pointed to by the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable within [Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/setup#using_the_client_library).

In the event that you want to change the credentials associated to your app, you can reconfigure any of the following mentioned above in your own terms. Just make sure to remove any configuration that was previously set to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

What are [service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts)?
A service account is a special kind of account used by an application or a virtual machine (VM) instance, not a person. Applications use service accounts to make authorized API calls, authorized as either the service account itself, or as Google Workspace or Cloud Identity users through domain-wide delegation.

For example, a Compute Engine VM can run as a service account, and that account can be given permissions to access the resources it needs. This way the service account is the identity of the service, and the service account's permissions control which resources the service can access.

A service account is identified by its email address, which is unique to the account.

[User-managed service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed)

You can create user-managed service accounts in your project using the IAM API, the Cloud Console, or the gcloud command-line tool. You are responsible for managing and securing these accounts.

Comment: Thanks. I know what is a service account. I have a few google accounts, so aware that each will have a unique id. But how can we tell which id to use?

Comment: According to the error message shown in your code 
"message" : "l*eal@api-project-8##429.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
Looks like you need to give this service account the storage.object.list role.
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#grant-single-role
Take a look in how to grant/change roles.

Comment: ok. we have to leave it there then. I am looking for a command. gcloud init etc. to set same email account related id to be used in all machines I use for testing. I am not interested to grant permissions for every email account related service id.